# Middleware for next-auth and i18n (next.js 13 with app router)

Tags: javascript, next.js, next-auth

I have next-auth set up (in my next.js 13 project with app router), it is working. Now I want to add internationalization to my app as described in the next.js docs. However, I don't know how to combine the two.

##### middleware working for next-auth

Every route in /user/ should be protected.

```js
export { default } from "next-auth/middleware"
export const config = { matcher: ["/(user/.*)"] }
```

##### middleware for next-auth & i18n

This is what I've come up so far. I18n seems to be working, but the routes /user/... are not protected.

```js
import { match } from '@formatjs/intl-localematcher'
import Negotiator from 'negotiator'
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'

export { default } from "next-auth/middleware"

let locales = ['en', 'de']
let defaultLocale = 'en'

function getLocale(request) {
    let headers = { 'accept-language': 'en' }
    let languages = new Negotiator({ headers }).languages()
    return match(languages, locales, defaultLocale) // -> 'en'
}

export function middleware(request) {
    // Check if there is any supported locale in the pathname
    const pathname = request.nextUrl.pathname
    const pathnameIsMissingLocale = locales.every(
        (locale) => !pathname.startsWith(`/${locale}/`) && pathname !== `/${locale}`
    )

    // Redirect if there is no locale
    if (pathnameIsMissingLocale) {
        const locale = getLocale(request)

        // e.g. incoming request is /products
        // The new URL is now /en/products
        return NextResponse.redirect(
            new URL(`/${locale}/${pathname}`, request.url)
        )
    }
}

export const config = {
    // '/(\w{2}/user/.*)' from nextauth (\w{2} because of /en/ or /de/); '/((?!_next).*)' from i18n
    matcher: ['/(\w{2}/user/.*)', '/((?!_next).*)'],
}
```

How do I combine the two?

Comment: were you able to resolve it? I'm facing the same problem right now

Comment: @in43sh No, sadly I was not yet able to fix that... Please let me know if you figure out a way to do so! I'll keep you posted about any success on my side as well.

Comment: thank you, I also have a question about it, it's almost identical

Comment: hey @in43sh, I just figured it out! Hope it helps you too.
See below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77524597/17760960

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out thanks to the help of @mateen-kiani and phind.com! This is how I combined the two middlewares:

```js
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import { match } from '@formatjs/intl-localematcher'
import Negotiator from 'negotiator'
import nextAuthMiddleware from "next-auth/middleware"

let locales = ['en', 'de']
let defaultLocale = 'en'

function getLocale(request) {
    let headers = { 'accept-language': 'en' }
    let languages = new Negotiator({ headers }).languages()
    return match(languages, locales, defaultLocale) // -> 'en'
}

export function middleware(request) {
    // cancel if exception
    const pathname = request.nextUrl.pathname
    const isException = ['/img', '/preview', '/icons', '/logo.svg', '/api', '/manifest.json', '/sw.js'].some((allowedPath) =>
        pathname.startsWith(`${allowedPath}`),
    );
    if (isException) return;

    // Check if there is any supported locale in the pathname
    const pathnameIsMissingLocale = locales.every(
        (locale) => !pathname.startsWith(`/${locale}/`) && pathname !== `/${locale}`
    )

    // Redirect if there is no locale
    if (pathnameIsMissingLocale) {
        const locale = getLocale(request)
        return NextResponse.redirect(
            new URL(`/${locale}/${pathname}`, request.url)
        )
    }

    // check if auth is required
    if (pathname.includes("/user")) {
        // check & handle if logged in
        const nextAuthResponse = nextAuthMiddleware(request)
        if (nextAuthResponse) {
            return nextAuthResponse
        }
    }

    // Continue if no NextAuth middleware response
    return NextResponse.next()
}

export const config = {
    matcher: [
        '/((?!_next).*)',
    ],
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of moving things around I've finally found the better solution that works for me.

```
"next-auth": "5.0.0-beta.5",
"next-i18n-router": "^5.2.0",
```

Just use the NextAuth middleware configuration:

**middleware.ts**

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth'
import { authConfig } from './auth.config'

export default NextAuth(authConfig).auth

export const config = {
  matcher: '/((?!api|static|.*\\..*|_next).*)'
}
```

And then mix authorized handler and i18nRouter on the auth.config file:

**auth.config.ts**

```
import { i18nRouter } from 'next-i18n-router'
import type { NextAuthConfig } from 'next-auth'
import { i18nConfig } from '@/locale/config'

const getLocaleFromPath = (pathname: string) => {
  const localeFromPathRegex = new RegExp(`^/(${i18nConfig.locales.join('|')})?`)
  const localeFromPath = pathname.match(localeFromPathRegex)?.[1]
  return { locale: localeFromPath, path: localeFromPath ? `/${localeFromPath}` : '' }
}

const checkCurrentRoute = (pathname: string, locale?: string) => {
  const checkPathnameRegex = (pattern: string | RegExp) => {
    const rootRegex = new RegExp(pattern)
    return Boolean(pathname.match(rootRegex))
  }

  return {
    root: checkPathnameRegex(`^/(${locale})?$`),
    dashboard: checkPathnameRegex(`^(/${locale})?/dashboard.*`),
    login: checkPathnameRegex(`^(/${locale})?/login.*`)
  }
}

export const authConfig = {
  pages: {
    signIn: '/login'
  },
  callbacks: {
    authorized({ auth, request }) {
      const { nextUrl } = request

      const locale = getLocaleFromPath(nextUrl.pathname)
      const dashboardUrl = new URL(`${locale.path}/dashboard`, nextUrl)

      const { root: isOnRoot, dashboard: isOnDashboard, login: isOnLogin } = checkCurrentRoute(nextUrl.pathname, locale.locale)

      const isLoggedIn = !!auth?.user

      if (isOnRoot || (isLoggedIn && !isOnDashboard)) {
        // If on root or logged in but not on dashboard, redirect to dashboard
        return Response.redirect(dashboardUrl)
      }

      if ((isOnLogin && !isLoggedIn) || (isOnDashboard && isLoggedIn)) {
        // Not logged in but on login OR logged in and on dashboard => allow access
        return i18nRouter(request, i18nConfig)
      }

      // Not logged in and not on login or dashboard => redirect to login page
      return false
    }
  },

  providers: []
} satisfies NextAuthConfig
```

**@/locale/config.ts**

```
export const i18nConfig = {
  locales: ['en', 'es'],
  defaultLocale: 'en'
}
```

In my case this successfully works. I've extracted the locale from pathname manually, and then reuse it in redirections. If no redirection for not authorized is needed, then return the i18nRouter so i18n is enabled.

For the rest of the config if followed this tutorial: [NextAuth tutorial](https://nextjs.org/learn/dashboard-app/adding-authentication)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it:

##### middleware.js

```js
export function middleware(request) {
  let locales = ['en', 'fr'];
  let defaultLocale = 'en';
  // Check if there is any supported locale in the pathname
  const { pathname } = request.nextUrl;
  const isPathAllowed = ['/img', 'img', '/api'].some((allowedPath) =>
    pathname.startsWith(`${allowedPath}`),
  );
  if (isPathAllowed) return;
  const pathnameHasLocale = locales.some(
    (locale) => pathname.startsWith(`/${locale}/`) || pathname === `/${locale}`,
  );

  if (pathnameHasLocale) return;

  // Redirect if there is no locale
  const locale = defaultLocale;
  request.nextUrl.pathname = `/${locale}${pathname}`;
  // e.g. incoming request is /products
  // The new URL is now /en-US/products
  return Response.redirect(request.nextUrl);
}

export const config = {
  matcher: [
    // Skip all internal paths (_next)
    '/((?!_next).*)',
    // Optional: only run on root (/) URL
    // '/'
  ],
};
```

##### en.json

```json
{
  "Index": {
    "title": "en title",
    "description": "en description"
    }
}
```

##### fr.json

```json
{
  "Index": {
    "title": "french title",
    "description": "french description"
    }
}
```

##### messages.js

```js
import en from './en.json';
import fr from './fr.json';

export const getSelectedLanguage = (lang) => {
  switch (lang) {
    case 'en':
      return en;
    case 'fr':
      return fr;
    default:
      return null;
  }
};
```

##### layout.js

```js
'use client';

import '@/app/globals.css';
import { SessionProvider } from 'next-auth/react';
import { NextIntlClientProvider } from 'next-intl';
import { getSelectedLanguage } from '@/internationalization/messages/messages';

export default function RootLayout({ children, params: { lang } }) {
  const messages = getSelectedLanguage(lang);

  return (
    <html lang={lang}>
      <body>
        <NextIntlClientProvider locale={lang} messages={messages}>
          <SessionProvider>{children}</SessionProvider>
        </NextIntlClientProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

##### page.jsx

```js
'use client';

import Link from 'next/link';
import { useLocale, useTranslations } from 'next-intl';

const HomePage = () => {
  const t = useTranslations('Index');
  const locale = useLocale();

  return (
    <>
      <main>
          <div className="container">
            <h1>{t('title')}</h1>
          </div>
      </main>
   </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense. However, how do you check in middleware.js whether the user is logged in and therefore allowed to access the "/user" route or if they have to be redirected to "/login"? Previously, next-auth/middleware handled that for me, but now how am I supposed to verify that?